# Can spring cloud stream kafka binder allow/deny retry for specific exceptions?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry

Is it possible to add a property to the application.yml to include/exclude certain exceptions from being retried in the policy defined below?  I swear that I read somewhere that there is a property for this, but now I cannot find it again for the life of me.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        topic-in:
          destination: topic
          contentType: application/json
          group: topic-group
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 3 
            backOffInitialInterval: 1000
            backOffMaxInterval: 1000
            backOffMultiplier: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation [Retry Template](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_retry_template).

> The `RetryTemplate` is part of the Spring Retry library. While it is out of scope of this document to cover all of the capabilities of the RetryTemplate, we will mention the following consumer properties that are specifically related to the RetryTemplate:
>
> ...
>
> **defaultRetryable**
>
> Whether exceptions thrown by the listener that are not listed in the `retryableExceptions` are retryable.
>
> Default: true.
>
> **retryableExceptions**
>
> A map of Throwable class names in the key and a boolean in the value. Specify those exceptions (and subclasses) that will or won’t be retried. Also see `defaultRetriable`. Example: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.retryable-exceptions.java.lang.IllegalStateException=false`.
>
> Default: empty.
>
> ...
>
> While the preceding settings are sufficient for majority of the customization requirements, they may not satisfy certain complex requirements at, which point you may want to provide your own instance of the `RetryTemplate`. To do so ...

Comment: This works perfectly for my needs! Thank you very much, Gary! Very quick response. :)

Comment: Got it. Thank you!